# How to implement Mongoose Populate in my scenario?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am a relatively new to using the populate feature in Mongoose. I have the need to populate the "_id" field of my "Customer" model with the list of Orders made by this customer. Here are the Schemas.

```
Customer_Schema = {
 name : string,
 phone : string,
 email : string

Orders_Schema= {
 customerID : string,  // This is the object ID of the customer from the "Customer_Schema"
 phone : string,
 email : string
```

Now I would like to know how to setup the "refs" in the Schemas and how to execute the populate command. For my end result I would like to get the Customer with all the order data under their "customerID".

Thanks.

Comment: You need to start by creating correct schemas. You won't be able to query the database let alone `populate` if you don't have your schemas defined. See [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) on how to create schemas and from there models. That will allow someone help you to debug and guide if you get stuck doing a `populate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a reference in the orderSchema that points to the "Customer" model.

```js
// Customer Schema
const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  phone: String,
  email: String
})
// Order Schema
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customerID: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Customer' // Reference to the Customer model
  },
  phone: String,
  email: String
})
// Define the models. Export models if necessary...
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema)
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)
```

Now you can use populate to get customer along with orders,

```js
Customer.findOne({ /* your query criteria .... */ })
  .populate('customerID') // 'customerID' should match the field name in the orderSchema
  .exec((err, customerWithOrders) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }

    console.log('Customer with orders:', customerWithOrders)
  })
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply. Allow me to shed some more light on my situation. I am trying to work with the populate feature on database collections that already exist beforehand. But the Schema's defining the collections never had a ref member.  The system has been up and running already for quite a while and data already exists in the database.  What are my options now to combine the customer's information into the order query in a single shot?

Comment: So it looks like you have omitted the most important part in your original question. I strongly recommend that you rewrite your original question to truly present your situation. Also, please add ACTUAL schemas/models with your question too, not hypothetical ones. make some queries to the db to fetch customer and order object and log them. Then add the logged objects with your question too. Hopefully then it will be possible to make some progress.